# Is there a cakephp component to create full APIs?

Tags: json, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, json-api

I'm trying to build a RESTful api for multiple models.

I found this:

```
class RecipesController extends AppController {

public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function index() {
    $recipes = $this->Recipe->find('all');
    $this->set(array(
        'recipes' => $recipes,
        '_serialize' => array('recipes')
    ));
}

public function view($id) {
    $recipe = $this->Recipe->findById($id);
    $this->set(array(
        'recipe' => $recipe,
        '_serialize' => array('recipe')
    ));
}

public function edit($id) {
    $this->Recipe->id = $id;
    if ($this->Recipe->save($this->request->data)) {
        $message = 'Saved';
    } else {
        $message = 'Error';
    }
    $this->set(array(
        'message' => $message,
        '_serialize' => array('message')
    ));
}

public function delete($id) {
    if ($this->Recipe->delete($id)) {
        $message = 'Deleted';
    } else {
        $message = 'Error';
    }
    $this->set(array(
        'message' => $message,
        '_serialize' => array('message')
    ));
}
}
```

But I'm trying to avoid duplicating all those methods in each controller that I need to create.   I've been looking for a component that will do all the CRUD operations that I can include in each controller.

1) Does such a component exist?
2) Am I overkilling this thing when I should just duplicate this basic controller for each model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your best bet would be this:

https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud

"CakePHP Application development on steroids - rapid prototyping / scaffolding & production ready code - JSON APIs and more"